# Converting boolean area of true and false to 1 or -1

Tags: python, numpy, loops, boolean

I an trying to create strat1 to be an array with dimensions 2^M,N in my loop. I need the values to be 1 or -1 randomly so the only way i could figure to do this would be to add the >0.5 at the end. This obviously will give true/false values. How could i code this to turn the true and false to 1 or -1 repsectively.
Thank you

```py
import numpy as np


for ca in np.shape(An):
    N = An[(ca - 1)]
    for M in range(Mi, Mm):
        crep = rep
        winr = np.random.rand(M, 1)
        strat1 = np.random.rand(2 ** M, N) > 0.5
```

Comment: Please indent the code. It's very hard to read.

Comment: You can use advanced indexing: `np.array([-1, 1])[np.random.randint(0, 2, (2**M, N))]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
strat1=np.random.rand(2**M,N)>0.5
# strat1 is True, False
out = strat1.astype(int) * 2 - 1
```

Out:

```
array([[-1, -1],
       [ 1,  1],
       [-1,  1],
       [ 1, -1]])
```

Or just

```
np.random.choice([-1,1], (2**M,N))
```